# Request.Post or None

Tags: django

In this [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yfjhLKL-_5Q&index=14&list=PLEsfXFp6DpzRcd-q4vR5qAgOZUuz8041S)

In minute 17:52 he have some staff on the screen.
First, This line:

```
form = SignUpForm(request.POST or None)
```

And second line:

```
print request.POST['mail']
```

i didnt undarstanad his enlish to understand two things:

1. What are the two parameters in the constructor are doing?
2. Why he say its not good to print the data like he did? what that does to the form sending?

Edit:
My view:
from django.shortcuts import render
from .form import SignAlbumForm
def SignUp(Request):

```
form = SignAlbumForm(Request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
    print form.save(commit=False).name
return render(Request, 'showname/index.html', {'form':form})
```

Comment: Surprisingly, I couldn't find a duplicate... if someone is able to I'd happily delete my answer

Comment: Why would u want to delete it....

Comment: @ededed stack overflow users like to try and keep the site clean from duplicates so the discussion for individual problems can all be found in one place.

Answer (score 3):

The first parameter of a Django form is for the forms data ([source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/forms.py#L72))

If the form was `POST`ed then it would have data and therefore construct the instance of the form with the data so it can be further validated later on using the `is_valid` method, if it had no data then it wouldn't be able to be validated since the [`is_valid`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/forms.py#L164) method calls [`is_bound`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/forms.py#L75) which looks to see if there is data.

For #2, you'll need to ask the author. Most likely because its pointless since noone will be looking at it, and even if they were it could potentially be insecure.

Comment: I tried to change its parameter to just "request.POST". and without "or None" its doing nothing differently. why is it?

Comment: Probably because `request.POST` *is* None wherever you're using it

Comment: I think i get you.. so it say - "bound the data to that form even if the data is ampty data" am i right?

Comment: If you change it to `request.POST`, then the form will be bound for GET requests, and you'll get errors for any required fields because they will be empty. If you don't have any errors, then either you don't have any required fields, or you are not displaying the errors in your view. You haven't shown your view or template, so I can't tell.

Comment: @Alasdair I saved edits and added an view code. You mean if i delete the "request.POST" that already exist? didnt got you well

Comment: I don't understand your comment - I didn't mention deleting at all. You might find the docs on [bound and unbound data](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/api/#bound-and-unbound-forms), and [this blog post](http://www.pydanny.com/the-easy-form-views-pattern-controversy.html) useful. If you add `print(form.errors)` to your view, then you should see the difference between `SignUpForm(request.POST or None)` and `SignUpForm(request.POST)` when you do a GET request.